# ASPNET 5 project is unable to find endpoint configuration (ServiceModel) utilised in a referenced DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, dll

I'm developing a new ASPNET 5 Web API project. I'm calling classes within a .NET 3.5 dll referenced in that project. Within the dll, there is a service reference providing certain required functionality.

Currently, when trying to call the classes in the dll, we get an exception similar to the following:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find endpoint element with name '****' and contract '****' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

I've tried copying the .config file with the same name as the referenced dll to the /lib/dnx451 folder but this has not solved the problem. I've also tried copying the .config file to the appropriate build directory in the artifacts folder.

I've also tried adding an app.config file to the ASPNET 5 Web API project, but this causes dnx to fail to build the project.

Due to the limitations of the work, we're unable to make any changes in the referenced dll.

I also wanted to try adding the service reference with the exact same name and contract, but an ASPNET 5 project does not give you an option to add a service reference (only a connected reference which is a different thing altogether).

Has anyone had any experience with this? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: There is no more ASP.NET 5, but only ASP.NET Core. Modify your question to match the facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to update Visual Studio and the .NET Core tooling to the latest. Then I created an app.config in the route directory and migrated the config from the dll into the new app.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically do this with out using config settings or you can add a rex file and in that file you can save your binding/contract details. 
The problem is config file is move with the dll so you can't get these details from a reference dll but rex file is move attached into the dll.